# How to create an equation in Java with decimals?

Tags: java

When I input whole numbers it comes out with the numbers I want. As soon as I input a number with a decimal it is off by a couple of %.

```
double theory = (((testMark*10)+(midMark*5)+(finalMark*2.5))/3);
double practical = (((labMark*10)+(assignMark*5))/2);
double finalAvg = ((practical+theory)/2);

System.out.println("\nTheory: "+df.format(theory)+"%");
System.out.println("\nPractical: "+df.format(practical)+"%");
System.out.println("\nFinal: "+df.format(finalAvg)+"%");
```

I want to calculate all grade together but some are out of 10,20,40 ect. That it why I have multiplied to make it out of 100.

Thanks.

Edit:

**Example of inputs and the answers:**

Enter your Lab mark out of 10: 7.5

Enter your Quiz/Test mark out of 10: 5

Enter your Assignment mark out of 20: 18

Enter your Midterm mark out of 20: 15

Enter your Final Exam mark out of 40: 32

Theory grade: 74.29%

Practical grade: 85%

Final grade: 77.5%

**My program outputs:**

Theory: 68.33%

Practical: 82.5%

Final: 75.42%

Comment: What is `df` in your code?

Comment: What are the types of testMark, midMark, finalMark, labMark, and assignMark?  What values do they have when the result is correct?  What values do they have when the result is incorrect?

Comment: @user3738870 Decimal format.

Comment: @VGR I edited my post.

Comment: Ryan, can you please remove your acceptance of my answer so that I can delete it?  Charles diagnosed your problem correctly - you are simply mistaken about what the output is _supposed_ to be.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code which contains `labMark =`.  Until we know whether labMark (and the other variables) are integral types or floating point types, the answer is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was the incorrect use of types. java int/int will still give you an int.  in this case 1 / 2 = 0... but 1 / 2.0 = 0.5.  this is because one of the operand is a double so the other number is also cast and a double is returned.

```
double theory = (((testMark*10)+(midMark*5)+(finalMark*2.5))/3.0);
double practical = (((labMark*10)+(assignMark*5))/2.0);
double finalAvg = ((practical+theory)/2.0);
```

Are you sure the formula you are using is correct?  is the example also using the same formula?

if you plug in the number and type it into a calcuator
(((5.0*10.0)+(15.0*5.0)+(32.0*2.5))/3) = 68.33333 which is what you got.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained why your changes make a difference.

Comment: Sadly didn't work, still giving me numbers that are 2-3% off.

Comment: I have replaced my downvote with an upvote because (i) you've now given an explanation, and (ii) there was actually no error, which you've pointed out.  OP is simply mistaken about what the program _should_ be outputting.

Comment: @Ryan, how are you, for example, expecting 85% for the practical?  (((labMark*10)+(assignMark*5))/2) = ((7.5 * 10) + (18*5))/2 = (75 + 90)/2 = 82.5